# What does this Eslint deprecation warning on React Component constructor really mean?

Tags: reactjs, constants, eslint, deprecated

I'm learning React and cant make sense of how to get rid of the Eslint warning.
I follow the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) that are suggested in the popup message and there it just done say anything what I can understand.

I removed the `super()` call then Eslint warn that I must make a super call
I [read](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599) that the constructor is being removed from React. even that post is 3 year old dunno what to make of this.

I also tried `this.state = this.parse();` outside the constructor and that did not work!
Supposedly one should be able to do also this `this.myHandler = this.myHandler.bind(this);` outside of the constructor but it's not acccepted.

Any clarity on this would be nice
[image]

Comment: Does your constructor take a second "context" parameter? I think that's the part that's deprecated.

Comment: Dunno about second parameter. I reda in that article that constructor is being removed from React what is that about

Comment: I removed the constructor super() then Eslint complaint there was no constructor super()

Comment: This answer might help your concerns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856962/understanding-why-super-is-deprecated-in-a-react-class-component

Comment: Thanks @MandarDeshpande very useful! I just remove `props` argument from `super(props)`

Comment: This is a wrong warning and can be ignored ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883401/react-native-context-and-deprecated-super-usage))