# Understanding why super() is deprecated in a React class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deprecated

I'm new to React and I'm learning about the React component lifecycle with the latest version of React. My "super" call of the partial code below is flagged with the deprecated warning shown. I've had trouble understanding this one, as a lot of documentation out there still uses "super", and I'm not sure what the successor is, even from the full article linked in the feedback. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
}
```

Here is the warning:

```js
constructor React.Component<any, any, any>(props: any, context?: any): React:Component<any, any, any> (+1 overload)
@deprecated
@see - https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html
'(props: any, context?: any): Component<any, any, any>' is deprecated ts(6385)
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [React native context and deprecated super usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63883401/1048572)? There is no `context` here, the code is fine actually, the warning is wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the optional context parameter is deprecated because it refers to the legacy React context (pre v16.3). What version of React are you using?

https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html

I have not used React with TypeScript. Maybe React mappings are out of date.

Comment: I'm using React 16.13.1. The thing that confuses me, is that I'm not even using that optional parameter.

Comment: What would the successor to constructor(props, context) be?

Comment: Looks like I can just call super() instead of super(props). I got the idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e

Comment: That should be fine unless you need to use `this.props` inside the constructor.

The successor is defined outside the component. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @Steven [React' docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) recommended using `super(props)` so I think you could leave it as is. The deprecation message is actually a bug and someone already submitted a [patch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47784) to fix it.

Answer (score 43):

You need `super(props);` only if you gonna use `this.props` in the constructor. Otherwise you can use `super();`
If you use `super();` in the constructor it is not a problem that outside of the constructor you will call `this.props`.
You can read about it in the following link:
https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(); //we forgot to pass props
    console.log(props); //{}
    console.log(this.props); //undefined
  }
  // ...
}
```

It can be even more challenging if this happens in some method that's called from the constructor. And that's why I recommend always passing down `super(props)`, even through it isn't necessary.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); //we passed props
    console.log(props); //{}
    console.log(this.props); //{}
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Explains super() but doesn't answers OP. the question was why it is marked deprecated.

Comment: I believe this was a kind of a bug which was not resolved at the time this answer was written. I've found this solution and explanation and share it if it could help someone to work out the problem. We could find more details in the others answers.

Answer (score 36):

`super(props);` isn't deprecated yet. The deprecation message actually caused from [a bug in React's type definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47784) and is already fixed as of *@types/react 16.9.51*. Just upgrade the package and you're good to go:

```
npm install @types/react
```

Comment: Solved it for me, whereas the others answers did not

Comment: It works, and I would suggest also adding `--save-dev`, so it would go to `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is a bug in jslint.  The code obviously isn't using the context parameter.