# Eslint warning about super(props) removing it breaks code

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I learn React and read code and now I see this Eslint warning

[image: (props(]

I refactor the code like this: removing `props`

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = this.parse();
}
```

Now Eslint is happy but the code breaks because of probably `props` cant be used in the `this.parse();`

How is this suppose to work?

Completet code:

```
// Copyright (c) 2017 PlanGrid, Inc.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

import CsvViewer from './csv-viewer';
import WithFetching from '../file-viewer/fetch-wrapper';

class XlxsViewer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.parse();
    }

    parse() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        const dataArr = new Uint8Array(data);
        const arr = [];

        for (let i = 0; i !== dataArr.length; i += 1) {
            arr.push(String.fromCharCode(dataArr[i]));
        }

        const workbook = XLSX.read(arr.join(''), { type: 'binary' });
        const names = Object.keys(workbook.Sheets);
        const sheets = names.map(name => XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[name]));

        return { sheets, names, curSheetIndex: 0 };
    }

    renderSheetNames(names) {
        const sheets = names.map((name, index) => (
            <input
                key={name}
                type="button"
                value={name}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ curSheetIndex: index });
                }}
            />
        ));

        return <div className="sheet-names">{sheets}</div>;
    }

    renderSheetData(sheet) {
        const csvProps = { ...this.props, data: sheet };
        return <CsvViewer {...csvProps} />;
    }

    render() {
        const { sheets, names, curSheetIndex } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="spreadsheet-viewer">
                {this.renderSheetNames(names)}
                {this.renderSheetData(sheets[curSheetIndex || 0])}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default WithFetching(XlxsViewer);
```

Comment: How does the code "break" if you don't use `props` argument? What specific issue? Also, looks like the warning is technically incorrect, there's posts about it like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856962/understanding-why-super-is-deprecated-in-a-react-class-component/63857001#63857001

Comment: It breaks here `const { data } = this.props;` The `data` does not exist

Comment: To be honest, it looks like this is a TypeScript bug (see a convo here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511) so you can safely ignore when it complains about `super(props)`. Microsoft should fix it and then you can just update your dependencies. For now, just ignore. You're right, you could pass through the props to the `parse` argument to if you like. It's a bit weird but should technically be functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advice, move the `parse()` part to `componentDidMount()`. the [constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) should be used in two cases only and shouldn't have any side-effects:

- Initializing local state by assigning an object to this.state.
- Binding event handler methods to an instance.

Also, not calling `super(props)` will result in you not being able to have the actual values inside `this.props` as it will be `undefined`.

A refactor to this code using [this.setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) would look like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import XLSX from "xlsx";

import CsvViewer from "./csv-viewer";
import WithFetching from "../file-viewer/fetch-wrapper";

class XlxsViewer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.parse();
  }

  parse() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const dataArr = new Uint8Array(data);
    const arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i !== dataArr.length; i += 1) {
      arr.push(String.fromCharCode(dataArr[i]));
    }

    const workbook = XLSX.read(arr.join(""), { type: "binary" });
    const names = Object.keys(workbook.Sheets);
    const sheets = names.map((name) =>
      XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[name])
    );

    this.setState({ sheets, names, curSheetIndex: 0 });
  }
  ...
}

export default WithFetching(XlxsViewer);
```

Answer (score 1):

we use super(props) in order to access props in constructor. you are not using props in constructor thats why eslint is giving error

so in order to remove error from eslint and code building

```
 constructor() {
        this.state = this.parse();
    }
```

use arrow function for binding

```
parse=()=>{
//code
}
```

Comment: When I do that it breaks here: `const { data } = this.props;` The data does not exis! maybe I should pass down `props` like so `parse(props);`

Comment: just use arrow function for binding . I have update the awnser