# React native context and deprecated super usage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, deprecated, super

I've been away from react native programming for a week and when I got back, after some VSCode updates, I have noticed that many of my `super(props)` calls in class constructors are now marked as deprecated. The reason seems to be some legacy context API issue, which is explained at this link: [React Native Legacy Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html)

I have understood some of the issues affecting context usage from the link. However, I am now a bit confused as to whether I need to make a call to `super()`, `super(props)` or not to make the call at all. My previous understanding was that, writing a class that extends a base class, always requires a call to `super()`. If the base class constructor also uses any props received in the constructor, passing the props with `super(props)` is also required.

In my code, I almost always extend `React.Component` if I need a stateful component. I rarely need to use `this.props` in `constructor()`s, and if I do, I only use it to set up the initial state object, after which I deal with changes in lifecycle methods. The following is how most of my class components would look like:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);  // super marked as deprecated here
        // super();    // super NOT marked as deprecated here

        this.state = {
            value: this.props.initialValue || 0
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
        // I would not actually do that, but for the sake of an example
        if (this.state.value > 10){
            this.setState({ value: 10 });
        }
    }

    increment = () => {
        const value = this.state.value + 1;
        this.setState({ value });
    }

    render = () => {
        return <View>
            <Text>Current value is: { this.state.value }</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.increment }>
                <Text>Add one!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me understand the correct usage of `super` in a React Native environment? I should also mention that I am using Expo SDK 38, which was released based on React 16.11. It is unclear to me whether the deprecation above also affects this version of React/React native or not.

Answer (score 6):

After looking further into this, it seems that my knowledge of the use of `super()` and `super(props)` is correct. The issue I am experiencing with `super(props)` being marked as deprecated is due to an erroneous deprecation marking in React's TS definitions.

What should've been marked as deprecated was the overloaded form of super, `super(props, context)`, which takes a `context` prop used by React's legacy context API.

The issue is better described and discussed at this (currently open) issue on Microsoft's TypeScript github page: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511

Until the issue is fixed, the deprecation warning can be safely ignored.

Comment: Seems like a [patch](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47784) is on its way.